# architectural design for image downloading

Tags: iphone, ios4, architecture

I am working on implementing optimized image downloading mechanism from remote server.

I have thought of two different approches.

1. Create one new thread and download all the images in asynchronous way in that single thread.

2. Create thread to download each image. Say i want to download 50 image then there will be 50 thread to download those images.

Which approach is better in terms of design and optimization?

Thanks,

Jim.

Comment: use EGOImageView..this one is asynchronous image dowloaded....https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading/

Answer (score 1):

Both your solution have pitfall.

1) Having only one thread means that you download only one image at time? This seems inefficient

2) For the same reason that having one download at time is a bad idea having 50 image that download simultaneously is a bad performance idea and will slow down everythings. Also consider that thread that download data are resource expensive for the system (network I/O, Disk I/O, etc..)

I can advice to do not reinvent the wheel and use an [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html)  that is the cocoa / cocoa touch implementation for a queue, that means you can add how many operation (where, in you case, operation are the image download) but you can specify the maximum number of concurrent operation (via the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` property).

NSOperationQueue handle all the multithreading stuff, and since iOS 4 it uses GCD to execute operations.